# Mobile Number should start from 3 in Oracle SQL and also check length should be 10

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, regexp-substr

I have mobile numbers in Oracle table column whose datatype is string

```
  3451111111
923452222222
 03451111211
```

I want SQL statement to select mobile numbers in this form 3451111113 only and check the length = 10.

I want a sub string that starts from character 3 and end at the end of string of length 10. It should neglect the 0, 92 at the beginning and start counting of string from 3 to onwards.

Comment: So - you should return only the last ten characters (ten digits), and only in the following situations: (1) The input is at least ten characters long; (2) The tenth digit counting from the **end** of the string is the digit 3. Do you know already that all the characters are digits, or can they be something else? (Like: parentheses, dash, spaces, perhaps letters, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_like()`:

```
where regexp_like(number, '^(0|92)?3[0-9]{9}$')
```

This matches either `0`, `92`, or nothing at the beginning of the string, then a `3`, and then 9 digits.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for help. But regexp_like is giving error in oracle. But my issue has been resolve by substr(number, -10)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  value LIKE '%3_________';
```

or, if you particularly want strings starting with `3`, `03` or `923` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  value LIKE '3_________'
OR     value LIKE '03_________'
OR     value LIKE '923_________';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '3451111111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '923452222222' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03451111211' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '312345678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3123456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '31234567890' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> | VALUE        |
> | :----------- |
> | 3451111111   |
> | 923452222222 |
> | 03451111211  |
> | 3123456789   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87492bc21dfacfceeb6bcedb4d27fc74)*

Comment: The OP stated explicitly in words, and his example supports it, that he only wants the substring of length ten to be returned - not the entire input value. Whether that makes sense or not is another matter. :-)

Comment: @mathguy The OP's last sentence says "It should neglect the 0, 92 at the beginning and start counting of string from 3 to onwards." Whether the OP just wants to check the last 10 characters or return them is ambiguous but it is a simple matter to change `SELECT *` to `SELECT SUBSTR( value, -10 ) AS phone_no` if they only want the last 10 characters returned.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 10 digits:

```
SUBSTR(phone_num,-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

To select only values where the last 10 characters are all digits beginning with 3:

```
select substr(str,-10)
from   demo
where  regexp_like(str,'3\d{9}$');
```

The filter will exclude for example `30 bananas` (the last 10 characters start with 3, but they are not all digits). It ignores any preceding characters, so for example `banana3123456789` would be reported as `3123456789`. It's not clear whether you want to exclude that as well.

`regexp_substr(str,'3\d{9}$')` gives you the portion of the string you want, if you just want to select it without filtering the results.